# git: как посмотреть какие изменения были в определенном файле, после git pull?

Tags: git

Когда делаю git pull, то в ответ мне также выводится список измененных файлов.

Например:

```
 src/Controller/Auth/TokenController.php | 259 ++++++++++++---------
...
```

как мне посмотреть, что это за изменения были в определенном файле ?

Comment: чтобы не клацать кучу команд, можно просто скачать какую-нибудь софтину по работе с гитом.

Answer (score 0):

Хммм, если я правильно понял вопрос, то я бы сделал так.

**Вариант 1**

```
$ git fetch // получаем изменения с удаленного репо
$ git diff master...origin/master // сраниваем
$ git pull // стягиваем и получаем такой ответ
Updating b3f34f3..d93kfk12
$ git diff b3f34f3..d93kfk12
```

**Вариант 2**

```
$ git reflog | grep -A1 pull | head -2
Тут тоже покажет хеши файлов и мы их сравниваем
$ git diff <хэш_коммита_1>..<хэш_коммита_2>
```

**Вариант 3**

```
git log --name-status origin/master..
И тоже сравниваем хеши файлов 
Желательно log выводить строкой
```